# Could not load GestureEventArgs from System.Windows.Input

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, assemblies

I have been searching for a solution but couldn't find any yet.

Situation is that I have a customcontrol that uses GestureEventArgs to apply some effect on the "Tap" event. The `GestureEventArgs` come out of the `System.Windows.Input` namespace. This is a WP7 (7.1) project by the way. If I use this control in an other WP7 (7.1) project my visual studio 2010 just crashes. No error or exception.

When I open the xaml file in Blend I get the following error:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   "System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs" from assembly
>   "System.Windows.Input, version= 2.0.5.0, Culture = neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"

The only cause that I see is that in the `Microsoft.Phone.Controls` namespace in my otherproject, also has a `GestureEventArgs`. But there isn't a complaint about ambiguity.

Anybody has been in this situation?
A fix would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this when I installed and referenced the Windows Phone Silverlight Toolkit. It adds a new GestureEventsArgs to System.Windows.Controls. I got around this by aliasing my using for System.Windows.Input

```
using input=System.Windows.Input;
```